# how to integrate the results of a sql mouths in variables

Tags: php, sql

I make a query in a loop
to get all user_nicename after 2022-09-04 00:00:00

It works great

This returns me the user_nicename that I display with the echo

I have for example as output

Alain
Rock
Paul
James

i would like every user_nicename
is contained in a different variable

```
$sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM _users  WHERE user_registered > "2022-09-04 00:00:00 "';
$recipesStatement = $bdd->prepare($sqlQuery);
$recipesStatement->execute();
$recipes = $recipesStatement->fetchAll();
$x=1;
// On affiche chaque donnee une à une
foreach ($recipes as $recipe) {
    //var_dump($recipe);
?>
    <p><?php 
    echo ' user_nicename= <span style ="color: #f90c2d;background-color: #f0e20e;">'.$recipe['user_nicename'].'" </span>; ?></p>
    
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic variables in a for loop:

```
<?php
$recipes = $recipesStatement->fetchAll();
for($i=0;$i<count($recipes);$i++)
{  
${"variable".$i} = $recipes[$i];
...
}
?>
```